# Connecting to database, possible options for multiple platforms

Tags: android, c++, sql-server, database, azure

I am currently developing an application that uses a database written with MSSQL. Once the project is complete, the database should be uploaded on a database service provider (e.g MS Azure) to supply an Android/iOS application with the data sets needed.
For now, starting and learning about databases (I am quite new to DBs/SQL, but have some experience in C++), I'd like to develop the "core functions" like reading, searching and writing specific data on the DB in a way that I can use the code as the "core" of the apps. What is the best way to do this? Which way to connect to the DB should be used to avoid troubles when moving it to the online-server?
I've done quite some research on the issue and found a lot about ADO.net, SQL Server Native Client, ODBC and SQLApi. But I didn't really manage to find out which solution is the appropriate to use in my case thus the libraries and drivers are available for multiple platforms. However, Visual Studio says that one can reuse Code on multiple platforms. Is that also possible for these APIs and extensions?
I hope you can help me, thanks in advance!

Comment: IMO, I think it's better if you could create some kind of API for your database operations. The mobile clients then interacts with this API via HTTP

Comment: Perhaps that is an option, but isn't a API quite a lot of effort? Can I run the API on the SQL server? And I would also be a bit concerned about possible security issues...

Comment: Sending the requests via HTTP could work, but isn't there anything i could use instead of a "Self-made" api?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The recommended approach by far is to develop an API. You will need a separate virtual machine or place to host your API. Then use REST commands to interact with the API that will provide Authentication, Authorization and Data Manipulation as requested.

It is not recommended to expose your DB to the outside world. The security risks are large since you would need to give your app read/write permissions to the database, so anyone could get anything. Trying to control security directly on your database would be a very difficult / nearly impossible task on a per user basis.

Comment: Thanks very much! So then it's going to be a web API. Do you accidentially know some good tutorials for setting up one in C++?

Comment: Developing a web API in C++ is not a task I would recommend undertaking unless you have lots of spare time and patience. I would recommend you look at either C# .NET WebAPI or Ruby on Rails. They are probably the most prominent and you will get the most help if you use those technologies. If you are using MSSQL, I would go with C# .NET WebAPI and Entity Framework. It may be a learning curve but it will still be done quicker than you developing an API in C++

Comment: Ok, thats it! I will take a look at .NET WebAPI. Thanks for your support!